# Django : Ajax form still reloads the whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am using a django form with ajax using this code:

```
 <form id="form-id">
     <p> Search : <input name="{{ form.query.html_name }}" value="{{ form.query.value }}" type="search" id="form-input-id" autofocus onfocus="var temp_value=this.value; this.value=''; this.value=temp_value">
     </p>
 </form>
```

and the Javascript code:

```
   $( document ).ready(function() {
       $('#form-id').on('change', function() {
           this.submit();
       })

      $('#form-id').on('submit', function(evt) {
          evt.preventDefault();

          var form = evt.target;

          $.ajax({
              url: form.action,
              data: $(form).serialize(),
              success: function(data) {
                  $('.results').html(data);
              }
          });
      });
  });
```

But here is the thing, everytime the submit event is triggered, I feel like the whole page is reloaded (it blinks). What could I do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: but how are you submitting the form, there is no submit button

Comment: I use the "change" event on the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `change` event is submitting your form and page refreshes. Delete it and add `change` event to second function, where you're currently waiting for `submit` event.

```
$('#form-id').on('change', function(evt) {
      var form = evt.target;
      $.ajax({
          url: form.action,
          data: $(form).serialize(),
          success: function(data) {
              $('.results').html(data);
          }
    });
});
```

To prevent submit on enter, add keypress event to function and detect when enter is pressed. Like this:

```
$('#form-id').on('change keypress', function(evt) {
    var key = evt.which;
    if (key == 13) {
        return false;
    } else {
        var form = evt.target;
        $.ajax({
            url: form.action,
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $('.results').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Key number 13 is enter. When it's pressed, nothing is returned. You could have also replaced `return false` with `evt.preventDefault()`. And for other keys, Ajax will be triggered.

Comment: That seems to have solved my issue but one last thing, if I press 'enter' while the focus is on the text input, it stills submits the form and reloads the page. Can I prevent this behavior as well?

Answer (score 0):

What if you add:

```
return false;
```

To your code, like so:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
       $('#form-id').on('change', function() {
           this.submit();
       })

      $('#form-id').on('submit', function(evt) {
          evt.preventDefault();

          var form = evt.target;

          $.ajax({
              url: form.action,
              data: $(form).serialize(),
              success: function(data) {
                  $('.results').html(data);
              }
          });
          return false;
      });
  });
```

Got this from:

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/15/how-to-implement-a-crud-using-ajax-and-json.html

> A very important detail here: in the end of the function we are
>   returning false. That’s because we are capturing the form submission
>   event. So to avoid the browser to perform a full HTTP POST to the
>   server, we cancel the default behavior returning false in the
>   function.

How I specify my form in html / django template:

```
<form id="form-id" action="required-url-goes-here" method="post">
     <p> Search : <input name="{{ form.query.html_name }}" value="{{ form.query.value }}" type="search" id="form-input-id" autofocus onfocus="var temp_value=this.value; this.value=''; this.value=temp_value">
     </p>
 </form>
```

The tutorial I pointed to above works in a different way then you do. It specifies, inside the ajax request:
- url
- type
- data
- dataType

It also uses a different way to reference the form, and it is the only way I know, so I can't judge if there is an error in the rest of your code.

Comment: I'm very new to Ajax, but since I read about 'return false;' I thought that might be it. One thing I see in you code is that you do no specify the type of request (post/get) and also you don't seem to specify the type of data you want back. Another thing I don't see is the action (url) you want your form to go to, not in your form tag, while you do try to use it in your jQuery code. I wonder if adding those things would have it work. I'll edit my example to show what I mean.